# Knockout: multiple select with objects not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using Knockout 3.2 and i'm trying to display a multiple select dropdown with some selected values, but the values are not being selected. The problem is that KO does not populate the 'value' attribute of the options:

```
<select data-bind="options: availableCountries, selectedOptions: chosenCountries, optionsText: 'name'" size="5" multiple="true">
    <option value="">France</option>
    <option value="">Germany</option>
    <option value="">Spain</option>
</select>
```

VM:

```
var viewModel = {
      availableCountries : ko.observableArray([{name:'France'}, {name:'Germany'}, {name:'Spain'}]),
        chosenCountries : ko.observableArray(['Germany'])
    };
```

If instead of object i turn `availableCountries` into a simple strings array, it works.

[You can see a live sample here](http://jsbin.com/naxazigemoza/1/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var viewModel = {
    availableCountries : ko.observableArray([{name:'France'}, {name:'Germany'}, {name:'Spain'}]),
    chosenCountries : ko.observableArray(['Germany'])
};
```

`['Germany']` is not `{name: 'Germany'}`!

And also if you, would write `chosenCountries : ko.observableArray([{name: 'Germany'}])`, this would lead to two different objects, with the same property `name` and the value `'Germany'`.

```
var viewModel = (function() {
   var self = {};
   self.availableCountries = ko.observableArray([{name:'France'}, {name:'Germany'}, {name:'Spain'}]);
   self.chosenCountries = ko.observableArray([self.availableCountries()[1]]);
   return self;
})();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

I changed the viewModel, to an instand called function which returns the viewModel.

*(function () {...})**()***<-call

http://jsbin.com/monasijufaya/1/edit?html,js,output